# How do I combine the output of two return variables into one in ArangoDB?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, aql

Beginner with ArangoDB here:

I have two outputs stored in two variables, say: `a` and `b`.
The structure of the items in variable `a` and `b` are exactly the same, but with different data. Example as follows:

```
a = {
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": "Lives"
}

b = {
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": "Childhood"
}
```

How would I combine the output from the two variables into one as follows?

```
{
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": ["Lives", "Childhood"]
}
```

Ideally, combine the two documents with user and city as common denominator, and action merged into an array? Not sure if Arango has a function like that natively, but any help towards the right direction would be a great help too!
I am open to writing the logic in my code instead, but I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

I've been playing around with `COLLECT`, `UNION`, and `MERGE` but with no luck.

Comment: How exactly should they be combined? Can you give an example of what the result should look like?

Comment: @mpoeter Ideally, with `user` and `city` as common denominator, and `action` merged into an array? Not sure if Arango has a function like that natively, but any help towards the right direction would be a great help too! 

I am open to writing the logic in my code instead, but I'd like to avoid that as much as possible.

Comment: Can you please update your question an provide a complete example of what your result should look like?

Comment: @mpoeter Okay. Done.

Comment: @bipster Can you write the desired result as json, not as (vague) text description?

Comment: @TomRegner Okay. Done.

Comment: @bipster does my answer help you solve your problem, or do you need further information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `data` as

```
LET a = {
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": "Lives"
}

LET b = {
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": "Childhood"
}

LET data = [a,b]
```

To get the desired result for `data`, this should get you started:

```
FOR i IN data
    COLLECT user = i.user, city = i.city INTO groups = i.action 
    RETURN {"user": user, "city": city, "action": groups}
```

That gives the desired result:

```
[
  {
    "user": "Thor Odinson",
    "city": "New York",
    "action": [
      "Lives",
      "Childhood"
    ]
  }
]
```

If you need more control over the variables returned, use `KEEP`:

```
FOR i IN data
    LET action = i.action
    COLLECT user = i.user, city = i.city INTO groups KEEP action
    RETURN {"user": user, "city": city, "action": groups[*].action}
```